# Add none UserPrincipal field to AD entry

Tags: c#, userprincipal

I am trying to add a none UserPrincipal field to a small application, but I just cannot get it to work. I tried several ways to do this simple task, but I cannot get anything to work for me. I am trying to ADD a field called Company to be inserted into the Active Directory, but Company is not a field that can be inserted...

Any ideas? Please post a code example if you have one. I have this so far:

```
public bool CreateNewUser(string sUserName, string sPassword, string sGivenName, string sSurname, string email, string phone)
    {
        if (!IsUserExisting(sUserName))
        {

            string sOU = "OU=Users,OU=External,DC=external,DC=rootteck,DC=com";

            PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext(sOU);

            UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(oPrincipalContext, sUserName, sPassword, true /*Enabled or not*/);

            //User Log on Name
            oUserPrincipal.Name = sUserName;
            oUserPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = sUserName + "@external.rootteck.com";
            oUserPrincipal.GivenName = sGivenName;
            oUserPrincipal.Surname = sSurname;
            oUserPrincipal.EmailAddress = email;
            oUserPrincipal.DisplayName = sGivenName + " " + sSurname;
            if (phone != string.Empty) { oUserPrincipal.VoiceTelephoneNumber = phone; }
            oUserPrincipal.PasswordNeverExpires = true;

            oUserPrincipal.Save();

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
            //return GetUser(sUserName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *a none UserPrinciple field* - what?? It's absolutely not clear what you're trying to do here.....

Comment: What do you mean by *none UserPrincipal*? Is that a *new user*? Also, are you getting an exception? What does it say?

Comment: Please make the question clear. The question is ambiguous.

Comment: It is clear! None userprincipal attribute that is not listed, all you have to do is extend the class, that I figured out myself for attributes that are not listed such as company, mobile, and etc.